# During debugging, how to evaluate a piece of code in the debug target VM?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jdi

During debugging, e.g. in Eclipse, one can evaluate Watch Expressions or Conditional Breakpoints. Typically, these are evaluated on the client side. For instance, when debugging from within Eclipse, it is Eclipse itself, not the debug target VM that evaluates these expressions. This can be quite costly, especially in the case of conditional breakpoints because the debugging VM (i.e. Eclipse) needs to become active on every breakpoint hit, even if the condition evaluates to false.

My question is now whether the debug protocol permits it to instead evaluate such expressions or conditional breakpoints in the debug target VM, such that the target VM only notifies the debugging VM when the expression/condition really evaluated to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the IDE (ab)using Hot Code Replacement to replace the method body by a body with an empty if block and putting the (conditional) breakpoint in there, I cannot find anything in http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp/jdwp-protocol.html that might help for doing this.

There is an `exprId` in EventRequest.Set which is documented as "for the future" and not exposed wia JDI BreakpointRequest, so I don't think this has or will ever work.

By the way, the evaluation happens inside the target VM (i. e. if you use equals() in your expression, equals() will run in your target vm), but the evaluation will be triggered from the debugging VM.